# WGS84 projection is invalid for aggregations

Tags: google-earth-engine, image, precipitation

I am trying to extract the pixel value from the last image of an image collection. The problem is that when I do so, I get an error stating the following:

[image: Error printed after executing code.]

This is my code for extracting the pixel value of the image:

```
var precipCol = imageCollection5.select(['hourlyPrecipRateGC'])
    .filterBounds(geometry)
    .filterDate(getFirst(new Date()), currentDate);

var lastPrecip = precipCol.reduce(ee.Reducer.last());

var precipNum = lastPrecip.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.last(), geom)
    .getNumber('hourlyPrecipRateGC_last').getInfo();
```

When I click on the inspector tab, the code editor does display the number as it should. The value I get when I click in the inspector is what I need to get from the code above.

[image: Inspector Tab Display]

The variable **geometry** is a polygon consisting of the following vertices:

[image: geometry var vertices]

The variable **geom** is the coordinate: (-106.224911, 31.548092).

The variable **currentDate** holds a string with the current date in YYYY-MM-DD.

function **getFirst(date)** returns current week's first date.

**imageCollection5** is the following source:

[image: source image collection]

What can I do?

Comment: Sounds like you need to put it in a projected coordinate system. See previous post: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/316303/reprojecting-with-google-earth-engine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this section

```
var precipNum = lastPrecip.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.last(), geom)
...
```

The issue is that lastPrecip is a temporary layer only stored in memory and doesn't have a nominal scale so GEE can't determine the scale by itself. There is a simple solution to this i.e. just specify the scale you want. So the code would now be

```
var precipNum = lastPrecip.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.last(), geom,30) //or w/e resolution you are aiming for
...
```

But using the **ee.Reducer.last()** reducer here is not that useful as this will return the last value from its inputs. So from within your polygon it is just returning you the value of last pixel in the array generated for reducer. Since the **last** reducer is already used to get last valid pixel from the collection, here you probably want to use something else for example *mean* which would mean mean precipitation in your region from the latest valid pixels. But if you only want to get pixel value from one pixel, it might be better to use point geometry and **sampleRegion** function.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error over a different computation, and using [`reproject`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/projections#reprojecting) helped: essentially forcing the projection of the new layer (`precipNum`) to a projection appropriate for the region.